# Closure of a set of real-valued functions...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ be set all of real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $S\subset \mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ such that $f\in S$ if only if there is an interval $I$ and a polynomial $p\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that
$$f(x)=p(x)$$
for all $x\in I$. Now consider the set $\bar{S}$, where $f\in \bar{S}$ if only if there is sequence of function $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $S$ such that 
$$f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$$ 
pointwise convergence for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. My question is this:
$$C(\mathbb{R})\subset \bar{S}?$$
where $C(\mathbb{R})\subset \mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ is set of all continuous functions. If it is not true, is there any counterexample?

Comment: $C^0(\mathbb R)$ is not a good notation as $C$ stands for continuity....

Comment: @JohnMa I see this notation in some articles about ring of continuous function before.

Comment: Your new assertion is not true for sure. There are functions in $S$ such that $f$ is not continuous (if $I\neq \mathbb R$).

Comment: @JohnMa If $f$ such that there is an interval such that $f$ constant  on $I$, then $f\in S$ and so $\bar{S}$. I guess that we can $m(I)\rightarrow 0$!!! (natural measure)

Comment: .... don't quite understand what you want to say here. What's $m(I)$?

Comment: @JohnMa please see my comment on answer post. $m(I)$ is Lebesgue measure i.e., length of interval.

Comment: Note that if you keep changing the question, the answer below would be invalided. Please go ask a new question.

Comment: @JohnMa ok, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a function $g\in C(\Bbb R)$. Choose an interval $I=[0,1]$. Take a sequence of polynomials $p_n(x)$ converging uniformly (and hence pointwise) to $g$ on the interval $I$. The existence of such a sequence is a standard result.

Now take $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}p_n(x),&x\in I,\\g(x),&x\notin I.\end{cases}.$$
Clearly, $f_n$ converges to $g$ pointwise and $f_n\in S$.

Hence $C(\Bbb R)\subset \bar S$.

Comment: If $I$ is not a closed interval, then whats happen?

Comment: If $I$ is not a closed interval, then we build that sequence of polynomials on the closure $\bar I$. If they converge uniformly and pointwise on $\bar I$, then they converge uniformly and pointwise on $I$, too.