# Following the previous question: Closure of a set of real-valued functions…

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Following the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440226/closure-of-a-set-of-real-valued-functions):

Let $\mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ be set all of real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $S\subset \mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ such that $f\in S$ if only if there is an interval $I$ and a polynomial $p\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that
$$f(x)=p(x)$$
for all $x\in I$. Now consider the set $\bar{S}$, where $f\in \bar{S}$ if only if there is sequence of function $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $S$ such that 
$$f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$$ 
pointwise convergence for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. My question is this:
$$C(\mathbb{R})\subset \bar{S}?$$
where $C(\mathbb{R})\subset \mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ is set of all continuous functions. If it is not true, is there any counterexample?

@TZakrevskiy: according his answer $C(\mathbb{R})\subset \bar{S}$. My second question is this:
$$\bar{S}=\mathcal F(\mathbb R)?$$
If it is not true, is there any counterexample?

Is the following argument true?

Let $g$ be any function and $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x+g(0),&x\in I_n,\\g(x),&x\notin I_n,\end{cases}$$  in which $I_n=[0,1/n]$, then $f_n$ pointwise to $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$! Therefore $\bar{S}=\mathcal F(\mathbb R)$.

It seems right. So I redefine my question as follows:

$S\subset \mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ such that $f\in S$ if only if there is an **unbounded interval** $I$ and a polynomial $p\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that
$$f(x)=p(x)$$
for all $x\in I$. In this case:
 $$C(\mathbb{R})\subsetneqq \bar{S}‎\subsetneqq‎ \mathcal F(\mathbb R)?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only answer the case where in the definition of $S$, the interval $I$ is always $(-\infty, \infty)$ (The other cases has been answered in another answer, if in the definition of $S$ you mean $I$ is depending on $f\in S$)

In this case $S = \mathbb R[x]$. I claim that

$$C(\mathbb{R})\subsetneqq\bar{S}‎\subsetneqq‎ \mathcal F(\mathbb R).$$

**Claim one**: $C(\mathbb R) \subset S$. Let $f\in C(\mathbb R)$. Then for each $n$, there is $p_n \in S$ so that

$$|f(x) - p_n(x) | <\frac 1n$$

whenever $x\in [-n, n]$. Thus $p_n$ converges pointwisely to $f$.

**Claim two**: $C(\mathbb R) \neq \overline S$. 
Let $f_n\in C(\mathbb R)$ so that 
$$f_n(x) =\begin{cases}
1 &\text{on }[-n, 0],\\ 
0 & \text{on }[\frac 1n, n],\\
 \text{linear} &\text{on } [0, \frac 1n].\end{cases}$$

Let $p_n \in S$ so that

$$|f(x) - p_n(x)|<\frac 1n$$

on $[-n, n]$. Then $p_n$ converges pointwisely to

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x\le 0 \\ 0 &\text{if }x>0.\end{cases}$$

**Claim three**: $\overline S \neq \mathcal F(\mathbb R)$.

(Might be a overkill) As pointwise limit of measurable functions are still measureable, $\overline S$ is contained in the set of all measurable function, thus is not $\mathcal F(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: For claim two: we have must be $f_n\in S$! and be polynomials!

Comment: I am then using $p_n \in S$ to approximate $f_n$, $p_n$ will also converge to that $f$ in claim 2 @Deliasaghi

Comment: Yes, you are right. From claim one; $f_n\rightarrow f$ is enough for claim two. thanks for elegant proof.

Comment: I think that if $f\in \bar{S}$, then $f$ on set  of finite measure is measureable function!

Comment: I was thinking about that too. Using some standard theorem in measure theory (might be).

Comment: But the problem is that whatever theorem of measure theory you used, you could at most got almost everywhere convergence. @Deliasaghi

Comment: may be, for any $f\in \bar{S}$, the set of all discontinuous point of $f$ has measure zero, because $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions.

Comment: Not really, one can construct a sequence of continuous functions going to the Dirichlet function. @Deliasaghi

Comment: Is the Dirichlet function the pointwise limit of sequence of polynomial functions?

Comment: No so sure @Deliasaghi

Comment: Can you check the http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117633/a-question-about-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-pointwise-convergent-analytic-funtio?

Comment: The reference that gives in answer, is not written in English.

Comment: I don't know Russian and German too. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Your argument works. You could simplify it a bit by making $f_n(x) = g(0), x \in I_n$ (remember that constant functions are also polynomials), but that isn't necessary. As for your redefined question, use $I_n = [n, \infty)$, and it isn't hard to see that $\bar{S} = \mathcal{F}(\Bbb R)$ still holds.

Unless by "unbounded interval", you meant unbounded on both sides. Then the answer is different because the only such interval is $(-\infty, \infty)$, which means $S = \Bbb R[x]$.